# Android timer and NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, networkonmainthread

I am using following code to update a list after certain time.

```
Myactivity {
    setTimer() {
        Runnable  r = new Runnable() {
            run() {
                if(!isListUpdated) {
                    update();//n/w operation
                } else {
                    show();//this is a UI operation
                    listupdated = false;
                }

                Handler.postDelayed(this,next); //repeat after next
            }

            new Thread(r).start();
        }
    } 
}
```

After 2 - 3 iterations it is giving `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Can somebody tell what is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 2):

You should **not do network operation in Main Thread**. Create a separate thread and do nw operation there.

You can use **AsyncTask**, **Service**  or **separate thread** . Where you ll do network operation. and update via BroadcastReceiver, Handler or AsyncTask.

Read about AsyncTask [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 2):

This exception usually occurs when you try to perform network operations in the main thread. Use an `AsyncTask` for your network operations.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `runOnUiThread` to perform UI operations in Non-UI Thread.

Your code snippet should be something like follows.

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        if (!isListUpdated) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    update(); //n/w operation

                }
            });

        } else {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    show(); //n/w operation

                }
            });
            listupdated = false;
        }

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, next);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

[NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html):

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
>   networking operation on its main thread.

so you need to Use [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html), [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)  , [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) , or [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) for Updating UI elements from background Thread.

---

an example using thread and [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) :

```
public void myThread(){
    Thread th=new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try
            {
                while(true) {
                    Current_Activity.this.runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                    //UPDATE UI FROM HERE
                        }
                    });
                }
            }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    };

    th.start();
}
```

Comment: I have updated the sample code , does it qualify as a separete Thread with runnable r to perform n/w operation?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using honeycomb version, you better use AsyncTask it will solve your problem.